# Find the numbers

Tags: mathematics

Here is a puzzle from the app **[Cryptocalc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pesteproducts.cryptocalc&hl=en)**:

[image]

To solve this, you need to replace each symbol with a number from 0 to 9.

Multiple symbols cannot have the same number.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer:

> [image]

or in text form:

> `|  6 x 45 = 270`
>  `|  x    -     -`
>  `|  2 x 27 =  54`
>  `|  =    =     =`
>  `| 12 x 18 = 216`

Explanation:

> First column: the product of [image] and [image] ends in [image], but is not equal to [image]. This only works if [image] is 6 and [image] is an even number, or [image] is 5 and [image] an odd number. The latter is impossible because that would make the second row 5 x 5? = ?? impossible; the product has to be three digits. So [image] is 6.

> Bottom row: the two digit numbers start with [image] and their product is three digits. This only works if [image] is a 1, 2; 3 would work but there's no multiple of 6 (30 / 36) that could be the first number in the bottom row.

> The only even multiples of 6 that work as the bottom number in the first row are 12 and 24. If [image] is a 4, the second row would become 4 x 4? which has three digits; one more than the last number in the second row. So [image] is 2 and [image] is 1.

> The bottom row now reads 12 x 1? = 216, so [image] is 8.

> The last number on the second row is even (because the product is even) and non-zero (because the top right number doesn't end in a six). 4 is the only possibility, so the second row must be 2 x 27 = 54.

> The factors on the top row are now known: 6 x 45 = 270.