# Find the numbers #2

Tags: mathematics

Here is a puzzle from the app **[Cryptocalc](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pesteproducts.cryptocalc&hl=en)**:

[image]

To solve this, you need to replace each symbol with a number from 0 to 9.

Multiple symbols cannot have the same number.

Comment: @NL628 division

Comment: @NL628 yes, each symbol means a digit

Comment: @NL628 you can refer this https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/58519/43489

Comment: @NL628 10 or less than 10

Comment: For the record, these would be easier to describe and document if you were to use letters instead of symbols. Manipulating GIMP took most of the time. :(

Comment: I'm glad you're eager to contribute puzzles here, but so far you've only posted content taken from the Cryptocalc app. While sharing really memorable puzzles found elsewhere is appreciated, it's not really fair (nor fair use) for you to gain rep here by predominantly (or *exclusively!*) posting run-of-the-mill content from other sources, even with attribution. Reposting numerous alphametics-style puzzles is a lot like someone posting a Sudoku book, one puzzle every few days... that shouldn't be okay here, for multiple reasons.  May I suggest you try creating some content of your own?

Comment: @Rubio yeah i understand :) okay I will try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from the top reading horizontally:

> `|  285 - 95  = 190`
>  `|    /    +      *`
>  `|   57 / 19  =   3`
>  `|    =    =      =`
>  `|    5 x 114 = 570`

Answer (score 4):

Use first row to get

> 0; fill in all 0s

Use second column to get

> 1; fill in all 1s

Continuing with this method:

> Use second column to get 9; fill in all 9s.
>  Use first row to get 2 and 8; fill in all 2s and 8s.
>  Use first column to get 5; fill in all 5s.
>  Use first column to get 7; fill in all 7s.
>  Use third row to get 4.
>  Use third column to get 3.
>  
>  [image]

Comment: oof now I feel bad for sniping